# Exchanging Facebook Auth Code for Access Token using the PHP SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am trying to build a server-to-server auth flow using the Facebook PHP SDK and no Javascript, as outlined [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/). So far, I have successfully created a LoginUrl that lets the User sign in with Facebook, then redirect back to my App and check the state parameter for CSFR protection.

My Problem is, that I can't seem to get the API-call working that should swap my Auth Code for an access token. I pillaged every similar problem anyone else that Google was able to find had encountered for possible solutions. 
Yet the end result was always the same: no access token, no error message that I could evaluate.

Researching the topic yielded the following advice, which I tested:

- The URL specified in the [App Settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) must be a parent folder of `$appUrl`.
- use curl to make the request instead of the SDK function `api()`

I've been at this for 2 days straight now and really could use some help.

```php
<?php

require '../inc/php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
// Setting some config vars

$appId = 'MY_APP_ID';
$secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';
$appUrl = 'https://MY_DOMAIN/appFolder';
$fbconfig = array('appId'=>$appId, 'secret'=>$secret);

$facebook =  new Facebook($fbconfig);

// Log User in with Facebook and come back with Auth Code if not yet done
if(!(isset($_SESSION['login']))){
    $_SESSION['login']=1;
    header('Location: '.$facebook->getLoginUrl());
}
// process Callback from Facebook User Login
if($_SESSION['login']===1) {
    /* CSFR Protection: getLoginUrl() generates a state string and stores it 
in "$_SESSION['fb_'.$fbconfig['appId'].'_state']". This checks if it matches the state 
obtained via $_GET['state']*/
    if (isset($_SESSION['fb_'.$fbconfig['appId'].'_state'])&&isset($_GET['state'])){
        // Good Case
        if ($_SESSION['fb_'.$fbconfig['appId'].'_state']===$_GET['state']) {
            $_SESSION['login']=2;
        }
        else {
            unset($_SESSION['login']);
            echo 'You may be a victim of CSFR Attacks. Try <a 
href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'">logging in</a> again.';
        }
    }
}

// State check O.K., swap Code for Token now
if($_SESSION['login']===2) {
    $path = '/oauth/access_token';
    $api_params = array (
            'client_id'=>$appId,
            'redirect_uri'=>$appUrl,
            'client_secret'=>$secret,
            'code'=>$_GET['code']
    );
    $access_token = $facebook->api($path, 'GET', $api_params);
    var_dump($access_token);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I found to do this is to extend the Facebook class and expose the protected getAccessTokenFromCode() method:

```php
<?php

class MyFacebook extends Facebook {

    /** If you simply want to get the token, use this method */
    public function getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirectUri = null)
    {
        return parent::getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirectUri);
    }

    /** If you would like to get and set (and extend), use this method instead */
    public function setAccessTokenFromCode($code)
    {
        $token = parent::getAccessTokenFromCode($code);
        if (empty($token)) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->setAccessToken($token);
        if (!$this->setExtendedAccessToken()) {
            return false;
        }
        return $this->getAccessToken();
    }

}
```

I also included a variation on the convenience method I use to set the access token, since I don't actually need a public "get" method in my own code.